# HashSet iterator() is linear not constant complexity?

Tags: java, iterator, hashset

I came across that iterator() of HashSet takes too much time. Here is some code example which proves the observation:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class Main {

    public static final int LENGTH = 100000;

    public static void calculate() {
        Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
        int part1 = 0;
        int part2 = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < LENGTH; i++) {
            set.add(i);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < LENGTH; i++) {
            long cur1 = System.currentTimeMillis();

            Iterator<Integer> it = set.iterator();

            long cur2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
            part1 += cur2 - cur1;

            int elem = it.next();
            set.remove(elem);

            long cur3 = System.currentTimeMillis();
            part2 += cur3 - cur2;
        }

        System.out.println("Total milliseconds to execute iterator() code: " + part1);
        System.out.println("Total milliseconds to execute remove() code: " + part2);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS").format(new Date()));
        calculate();
        System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS").format(new Date()));
    }
}
```

The result of the run is:

```
2023-08-28 14:05:51.080
Total milliseconds to execute iterator() code: 9477
Total milliseconds to execute remove() code: 18
2023-08-28 14:06:00.595
```

I checked the documentation and implementation of iterator() and only saw that it should be a constant time but it doesn't seem so.

Does anybody know why is it takes so much time?

Comment: Creating an iterator does a lot more things than removing an element. The two things are unrelated and therefore not meaningfully comparable.

Comment: Shudder. Use `it.remove();` **not** `set.remove(elem);`. The [`Iterator.remove()` Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove--) says (in part) *The behavior of an iterator is unspecified if the underlying collection is modified while the iteration is in progress in any way other than by calling this method.* Also, you might want to try using a [`LinkedHashSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) a plain `HashSet` doesn't guarantee iteration order. `Iterator<Integer> it = set.iterator();` should be outside the loop.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Doesn't matter in this case. OP doesn't do anything with the iterator afterwards.

Comment: OP, how do you conclude from measuring a single collection that it is not constant time? If it takes constant 0.1 ms, you'll get 10000 ms when calling the method 100k times – which matches your numbers.

Comment: I have to wonder what you read, and if you interpreted it correctly. Your code only proves creating an iterator takes some time. It doesn't attempt to demonstrate the time it takes correlates to the size of the problem. And, as others have pointed out, it is an "apples to oranges" comparison.

Comment: There's an interesting and significant reason why this is taking so long, discussed in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`iterator()` normally takes constant time -- but to be specific, it takes time linear in the position of the first element in the hash table to create the iterator.

This is O(1) on average, except that each time, you remove the first element in the hash table, meaning that `iterator()` actually ends up taking linear time in how many `remove`s you've done.  Let me diagram this with a simple example.

Let's imagine you have a hash table with four elements in four hash buckets, with elements assigned to buckets in some nonsensical order:

```
bucket 0: 4
bucket 1: 2
bucket 2: 1
bucket 3: 3
```

Now you create `iterator()`, and its first element is 4.  You remove it.  Now it's

```
bucket 0: none
bucket 1: 2
bucket 2: 1
bucket 3: 3
```

Do this two more times, and on the last run it's

```
bucket 0: none
bucket 1: none
bucket 2: none
bucket 3: 3
```

...so it has to iterate through the whole thing to find that first eleement.

In general, it is the case that `iterator()` performs worse on basic `HashSet`s after removing.  From the Javadoc:

> Iterating over this set requires time proportional to the sum of the HashSet instance's size (the number of elements) plus the "capacity" of the backing HashMap instance (the number of buckets).

Since you have created a `HashSet` with capacity for `LENGTH` elements, iterating the whole set in general takes O(LENGTH).  You have simply created an environment that's the worst possible case for `iterator()`.

If you had done, for example, `remove(i)`, it would certainly perform better, though it'd still perform worse over time, and certainly take O(n) for the last remove.

If you find yourself saying, "this is silly, why doesn't
Java do something better" -- well, 99.9% of code doesn't do this, and for the fraction that does, `LinkedHashSet` fixes the whole issue.

Answer (score 2):

You're misreading the documentation, which [says (e.g., in version 8)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html):

> This class offers constant time performance for the basic operations
> (add, remove, contains and size), assuming the hash function disperses
> the elements properly among the buckets.

In other words, the time it takes to add or remove an element in the set, or to evaluate whether an element is in the set, or to check the size of the set, is constant. Constructing an iterator as you've done in the code using `set.iterator()`, which you'd do if you wanted to go through each element one at a time, isn't the same thing; that's like comparing the time it takes to build a bicycle with the time it takes to ride it a mile.

Comment: Thanks for the reply I totally agree with your comment. I checked the implementation of iterator() function in HashSet and I don't see anything what might took so much time: public Iterator<E> iterator() { return map.keySet().iterator(); }. It gets me puzzled what exactly is happening behind the scenes. (P.S. I also checked HashMap iterator() implementation and it looks simple too)

Comment: @LouisWasserman Execution of iterator() 100k times takes 9 seconds. That's seems too slow for me.

Comment: @olzh13 it seems that you did not dig deep enough. If you further dig into the methods and constructors called through `map.keySet().iterator()` you arrive at https://github.com/openjdk/jdk17u/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/HashMap.java#L1585: `do {} while (index < t.length && (next = t[index++]) == null)` which certainly is not a constant time operation.